# Instaling MySQL with PHP Desktop

Tags: php, mysql

So I want to turn my PHP web app into executable Windows app. For this I am using *PHP Desktop*. But MySQL doesn't come with it. What I should include  in the files so people who instal the app have working phpmyadmin DB. I don't want them instaling XAMPP.

Comment: Shipping MySQL with your application is going to be a big mistake as administering MySQL is often difficult and well beyond the ability of average users. Instead use an embedded database like SQLite with no server process. It's also the case that PHP is not exceptionally well suited for desktop applications as compared to things like C# .Net, C++, or even Electron (JavaScript), though in those cases the same problem with using MySQL exists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use sqlite for it, or require user install mysql manual.